# Turn Package.swift file into binary XCFramework

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework, swift-package

Someone in my company created a `Swift package` `SDK` and now I was tasked to publish it for the customer in a `binary` way so that the end customers that will use the `SDK` will not be able to see the `source code` of it. This is how the SDK is built:
[the SDK in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgB2k.png) (p.s. the build folder is empty)

From my reading on the subject I understand that I need to export the files into an `XCFramework` file. However, the vast majority of guides I've encountered explain how to make this progress from a `framework`, and not from a `package` like in my case..

The only guide I found that seems exactly like what I need is [this](https://mustafa-ysf.medium.com/creating-xcframework-from-swift-package-e8af6f44501f) one, however I get an error right on the first relevant terminal command of `xcodebuild -scheme [my scheme name] -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release ARCHS="arm64" BUILD_DIR="./Build"`. This is the main error line I get: `xcodebuild: error: Building a Swift package requires that a destination is provided using the "-destination" option. The "-showdestinations" option can be used to list the available destinations.`. Why would I need to specify a destination? I want the SDK to work for all the devices (ios 13+). Non of the forums I searched in online helped me solve this.

I also read Apple's instructions [here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev544efab96) but got very confused about how the terminal command in step 2 is supposed to look like in my case. Are some of the fields mandatory and some are not?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are working with iOS only and you need an xcframework for both device and simulator architectures, in order to generate an XCFramework from a swift package you need to:

1. Mark your Package as `.dynamic` (i.e. `.library(name: "Foo", type: .dynamic, targets: ["Foo"])`)
2. Archive the project for both simulator and device. This will generate a .framework file for each architecture.
3. Copy `Modules` folders (if any) into the .xcarchive files
4. Copy the bundles (if any) into the .xcarchive files
5. Create the xcframework with the frameworks created in step 2

Here's a bash script, based on the one from [this swift forums post](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-build-swift-package-as-xcframework/41414/4), to create an XCFramework from a swift package (in my case, I have my package inside an xcworkspace. I didn't try it as a standalone package, not sure if that can be done):

Change the input parameters as needed :), but most importantly replace `<Your project name>` and `<your workspace>`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_NAME="<Your project name>"
PROJECT_DIR="./Packages/${PROJECT_NAME}" # Relative path to the directory containing the `Package.swift` file
BUILD_FOLDER="./build"
OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output"
SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-iphonesimulator.xcarchive"
DEVICE_ARCHIVE="${OUTPUT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-iphoneos.xcarchive"

rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

# 2 iterations: 1 for device arch and another for simulator arch
for PLATFORM in "iOS" "iOS Simulator"; do
    case $PLATFORM in
      "iOS")
        ARCHIVE=$DEVICE_ARCHIVE
        SDK=iphoneos
        RELEASE_FOLDER="Release-iphoneos"
      ;;
      "iOS Simulator")
        ARCHIVE=$SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE
        SDK=iphonesimulator
        RELEASE_FOLDER="Release-iphonesimulator"
      ;;
    esac

    # Step 2
    xcodebuild archive \
      -workspace <your workspace>.xcworkspace \
      -scheme $PROJECT_NAME \
      -destination="generic/platform=${PLATFORM}" \
      -archivePath $ARCHIVE \
      -sdk $SDK \
      -derivedDataPath $BUILD_FOLDER \
      SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
      BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

    FRAMEWORK_PATH="${ARCHIVE}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"
    MODULES_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_PATH/Modules"
    mkdir -p $MODULES_PATH

    BUILD_PRODUCTS_PATH="${BUILD_FOLDER}/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/${PROJECT_NAME}/BuildProductsPath"
    RELEASE_PATH="${BUILD_PRODUCTS_PATH}/${RELEASE_FOLDER}"
    SWIFT_MODULE_PATH="${RELEASE_PATH}/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
    RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH="${RELEASE_PATH}/${PROJECT_NAME}_${PROJECT_NAME}.bundle"

    # Step 3
    if [ -d $SWIFT_MODULE_PATH ] 
    then
      cp -r $SWIFT_MODULE_PATH $MODULES_PATH
    fi

    # Step 4
    if [ -e $RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH ] 
    then
      cp -r $RESOURCES_BUNDLE_PATH $FRAMEWORK_PATH
    fi

done

# Step 5
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
 -framework "${DEVICE_ARCHIVE}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" \
 -framework "${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" \
 -output "${OUTPUT_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcframework"
```

When the script ends, you will see 3 files in the output folder:

- Device xcarchive
- Simulator xcarchive
- XCFramework

You can remove the xcarchives, as you won't need them anymore (you can also update the script to do that for you).